New Drugs approved - monthly list
Is there any API which would list all drugs that are approved between two dates showing the approval date?
Thanks
Manoj

"All drugs"? In which country? I don't know anything about drug datasets, but to possibly get an answer, you probably need to provide a lot more detail about what you want.
